# How to install JavaScript libraries in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For a JavaScript library that doesn't have a rubygem version, how do I install it in Rails?

I checked the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), and neither [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) nor [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) seem to explicitly address how to install JavaScript libraries.

Comment: Normally you would save the library in `/vendor` directory and require it in `application.js`

Comment: try bower to install/manage your essential javascript libraries..and install them on vendor/assets, add it to `config.assets.precompile` if you want them compressed then add them on your layouts/view templates wherever it is required. gemified versions of these libraries are heavy while you can filter the files which are only required to your application with bower [http://dotwell.io/taking-advantage-of-bower-in-your-rails-4-app/]

Answer (score 0):

Add the javascript files to your app/assets/javascripts folder.

```
> cp my_js.js path/to/my_rails_app/app/assets/javascripts/
```

Make sure that the layouts that need the file contain a line to include the application javascript:

```
# app/views/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

And in your application.js file, make sure the tree is required in the comments:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
...
//= require_tree
```

Restart your server, and the javascript should now be included

Answer (score 0):

If you have just an one file, then you can copy and past it into `app/assets/js` folder. `require_tree` should cover for you, which is that in `layouts/application.html.erb` this line `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` will include everything.

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
...
//= require_tree .
```

If you would like to use bower, then set it to `vendor` folder. and add into `appl..js` file like below.

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require angular
//= require angular-cookie
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
```